# Excel count instances of a value error

Tags: excel

I need to count the amount of times a value shows up in the B column and display it in 3 seperate fields. What I came up with was this piece of code:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B6716,"0")
=COUNTIF(B2:B6716,"1")
=COUNTIF(B2:B6716,"2")
```

But no matter how I enter this It keeps telling me the formula is incorrect. I tried removing the " around the three numbers aswell btw and even in order to test it I even used some words but it just won't work. Any idea how I can get this to work?

The error:
[image: The error]

Comment: Thanks lol, the example I found used a , instead of a ; and I didn't even realize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B416; "=0")
```

As a criteria, you should rather put some string that appended to tested value forms a condition, not a particular number. This way, you can formulate more fancy criteria, like:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B416; ">100")
```